# Car and bike. How to keep it in good condition when unused for two months?

Tags: motorcycle, battery, car

I've seen [this post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/car-sitting-for-several-months-what-should-i-do-to-keep-it-running-well), [this one](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/how-should-i-prevent-my-battery-going-flat-when-i-leave-my-car-alone-for-a-month) and [this one](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2281/is-it-okay-to-leave-a-car-for-5-months-without-driving-it). But what about a bike like a [Hero Honda Splendor+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero_Honda_Splendor)? Apart from keeping the [fuel petcock off](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5129/why-should-the-fuel-petcock-valve-be-turned-to-off-position-when-not-using-the), what else should be done to ensure that the bike runs fine after two months of not using it?

I'd assume removing the negative connection to the battery as done for the car, would be necessary/sufficient? The tyres should be filled with air and having at least some fuel in the fuel tank, is what I can think of. Any suggestions to correct me?

Am in India, and it's the monsoon now. Although the car and bike are away from the rain, I don't think good [trickle chargers](http://www.carsdirect.com/car-repair/how-to-use-a-trickle-charger) are available here. So looking for alternative knowledge on what can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So a few things you can do:

- Ensure the tank is completely topped off.
- If carbureted (I believe your's is), turn off the pet cock, start the engine, and run it out of fuel. This will ensure your carburetor is nearly (if not completely) dry, which will allow it not to build up varnish from sitting fuel.
- Put fuel stabilizer in your fuel. I use [Sta-Bil](http://www.goldeagle.com/product/sta-bil-fuel-stabilizer) in your fuel, but I don't know what you have available in India. This will ensure your fuel is fresh when you go to start it the next time.
- If a battery tender (like a trickle charger) is not available (this would be my first choice), take the negative battery lead off the battery. I would highly suggest you attempt to get a battery tender as it will get you through the down periods much better than a trickle charger or nothing at all. IIRC, a trickle charger will continue to charge the battery at a low rate (like 2A), where as a tender will top off the battery, then only charge the battery as needed to keep it in shape for when you do need it.
- As long as tires will maintain air over the period, fill them up to capacity (if below) and they should be fine. If they won't, get them fixed and then do the same.

A couple of months really isn't too long of time to have a bike/vehicle sit, but I don't blame you for taking precautions to ensure it's taken care of. Also, don't forget to turn your pet cock on prior to trying to start ... that makes for hot starters, worn out battery, and a frustrated rider ;-)

Comment: carbureted, yes.

Comment: Car batteries have low self-discharge rate so taking the negative terminal off should be sufficient. You can recharge it before starting, but I have few sitting in my basement. One of them was charged to full and left for about a year or more. I recharged it again and it lost about 5% of energy so if there is nothing draining it out and the battery itself is in good condition you won't even notice it was sitting there for 2 months.